# How to convert image CMY to halftone in Swift IOS?

Tags: ios, swift4

How to convert image CMY to halftone in Swift IOS?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used a long time back

Calling a function which converts the simple image to CICMYKHalftone image -

```
let myConvertdImage = simpleCMYKHalftoneFilterMethod(inputImage: ImageView.image!)
```

and the actual function looks like this -

```
func simpleCMYKHalftoneFilterMethod(inputImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
        // Create and apply filter
        // 1 - create source image
        let sourceImage = CIImage(image: inputImage)

        // 2 - create filter using name   CICMYKHalftone   CIPhotoEffectNoir
        let myFilter = CIFilter(name:"CICMYKHalftone")

        // 3 - set source image
        myFilter?.setValue(sourceImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        // 4 - create core image context
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)

        // 5 - output filtered image as cgImage with dimension.
        let outputCGImage = context.createCGImage(myFilter!.outputImage!, from: myFilter!.outputImage!.extent)

        // 6 - convert filtered CGImage to UIImage
        let filteredImage = UIImage(cgImage: outputCGImage!)

        // 7 - set filtered image to preview
        self.ImageView.image = filteredImage

        //image base64 string
        let userImage:UIImage = self.ImageView.image!
        let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(userImage)! as NSData
        imageBase64Str = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

        return filteredImage
    }
```

Hope this helps you. Happy coding :)

Comment: Hi Prashant Gaikwad, Thanks for your answer.

Please consider my updated question.

Comment: @Nagaraja Prashant has posted an answer to your original question. Now if you have another question, please post it as a separate question, do not modify this one. Thank you.